# Correct naming of properties in Angular2+

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to write this:

```
private _name:string;
public get name():string{
    return this._name;
}
```

But the Angular Style Guide advise against it: https://angular.io/styleguide#!#03-04

Am I thinking wrong?
What should I use instead?

Comment: Angular uses it itself https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_style.ts#L35-L43

Comment: Have you added the right link to the style guide? Because there is nothing against your approach from the provided link.

Comment: @DenisReshetniak "Avoid prefixing private properties and methods with an underscore."

Comment: @Dinistro Yap, I see. My bad, sorry. I wouldn't use underscore prefix because you already have `private` keyword. And intellysence will help you with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're using is TypeScript standard. Since you can't name your variable name, because `get name()` will be compiled to `whatever.name`, you have to use the underscore.

Angular isn't any different there because it uses TypeScript itself. They just say you should use name if you don't have a specific getter or setter method for that property.

I don't know if your code is just an example but it wouldn't make sense since the property name simply would be public in the end anyway.

Comment: It would make sense if he/she has a setter that is doing some logic that is not showed in the example :)

Comment: Thank you for your answere. This is an example, but I like to do this because the IDE would in this case show en error if I try something like: whatever.name="George"

Comment: 1) What IDE are you using? 2) You mean if you use this attempt the IDE complains about it?

Comment: It would of course since there is no `setter` for `name`

Comment: @FredrikLundin That is the point. I want the IDE to give errors when I do something it is not supposed to. And I want the the code completion not to work, when I set something I'm not supposed to. I'm instinctively using encapsulation.

Comment: @Wernerson I'm using Jetbrains PhpStorm. Yes it complains. I can only set value to a property if there is a set method.

Comment: @Skvupp I don't get your question then. If your goal is that the IDE complains when you do this, and it seems like it does, what exactly do you want?

Comment: @Wernerson It is not an error. Everything works as I want to. My question was about the naming convention and what I should do if I wasn't supposed to use underscore.

Comment: @Skvupp You don't have to change anything. According to the common TypeScript styleguide this is correct. See: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Classes.md#accessors

Comment: Thank you @Wernerson! This was my debut on Stackoverflow and it was very helpful!