# Usage of class in 'typing' the variable (vs interface) and 'modelling' (for Typescript Angular 2 project)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Let say I have a model class

```
class User {
    name: string;
    email: string;
}
```

and a service related to user

```
class UserService {
    getInfo (usr: User) {
        console.log(usr);
    }
}
```

The `usr: User` is an input parameter for `getInfo` method, and no `User` class is created for that statement since the `User` just "typing" the `usr`. Instead, we can replace it with interface, isn't it?

Yeah, I am aware of Angular 2 official guide that suggest try to use class instead of interface

> quote: "**Consider** using a class instead of an interface"

and I can accept it, although it is weird.

My question is, WHY WHY WHY use a class to "type" a variable, since we don't create any instance from it? We can replace the `UserService` class as shown below, and it works too...

```
class UserService {
    getInfo (usr: any) { //this work too
        console.log(usr);
    }
}
```

(please correct me if I am wrong)

**[#1]** This will create a property that have the class content

```
class UserService {
    usr: User = User; //usr = { name: '', email: ''}
}
```

**[#2]** This is used by Angular 2 to do dependency injection (assuming I have listed the `User` as provider), and in this case, it is similar to #1 as we are just copy the `User` to `usr`. (usually, we do DI on service, instead of model, since injecting model will have the same *effect* as "assigning" it to a variable, am I correct?)

```
class UserService {
    constructor (private usr: User) {}
}
```

**[#3]** And this confuse me... because why we still do it since we don't need it? (because nothing is created, no usage here)

```
class UserService {
    usr: User; //usr: any; (?)
}
class UserMoreService {
    getInfo (usr: User) {console.log(usr);} //usr: any (?)
}
```

Lastly, may I know what is the **motivation** behind to create a "model" class in Angular 2 project?

We have the component to display data, and to get the data, we can ask it from related service, and the service will get it from the server.

Can you see this? we don't need a "third party" model to "hold" the data, because everything can be done without declaring a "model" class. Can please tell me when to create a "model"? I don't see any reason to create that...

Answer (score 1):

It is not a must but just a suggestion.

**Why?**

> An interface-class can be a provider lookup token in Angular dependency injection.

Source: https://angular.io/styleguide#!#03-03

Creating a class is pretty much the same work with respect to creating an interface but you can use these classes as a class-interface in your provider tokens later on.

---

```
{ provide: MinimalLogger, useExisting: LoggerService },
```

This can be used as a type of inheritance among Angular providers.

```
export abstract class MinimalLogger {
  logs: string[];
  logInfo: (msg: string) => void;
}
```

> When you use a class this way, it's called a class-interface. The key benefit of a class-interface is that you can get the strong-typing of an interface and you can use it as a provider token in the way you would a normal class.

Source: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#class-interface

---

**Side note:** If you're sure that you aren't going to use it as a provider token or so IMO you **should be using an interface** since they disappear after the code is transpiled to JavaScript. Hence, they don't use your memory.

> Using a class as an interface gives you the characteristics of an interface in a real JavaScript object.
>
> Of course a real object occupies memory. To minimize memory cost, the class should have no implementation

Comment: Ok, I get it. So, if I need a "global" variable (let say `CurrentUser`), I can declare a model class (`class currentUser`) and set it as a top-level `provider`, then it can be accessed everywhere. However, in Angular 2, we usually create a `service` and send data to the component, and let the component to "hold" those data. Is this the Angular 2 trend? I mean the design pattern... If we desperately need to have a top-level model to hold data, we usually "inject" it in a singleton top-level service, and let the service to "hold" those data, am I correct?

Comment: @BooYanJiong IMO it is correct and you should try to keep things as simple as possible but again simple can be a relative term :-) As for the Angular 2 trend, even Angular team is not using their style guide from time to time (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44388818/correct-naming-of-properties-in-angular2#comment75777265_44388818). For holding data; services can "hold" data if that is a shared service or maybe there's another implementation that I can't remember right now. Overall your question is a little opinion based as you would appreciate but as I think you are on the right track.